# Bluemix Cloudant Incremental Data Push

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, dashdb

I am using Bluemix data services for some of our large data processing tasks.
The raw data comes into Cloudant and we are pushing this to DashDB using the warehouse service with in cloudant and it pushes data to dashDB.

When the warehouse runs it pushes new/updated rows to dashdb but also looking at the warehouse status column it says '5/5 revisions warehoused' , which means it is also pushing and overwriting the existing rows.

I want to make sure only changed rows are pushed to dashdb. I have looked at since_seq attribute but looking at the docs it looks like this is for cloudant to cloudant replication. Can someone suggest a way to do this incremental push specifically to dashdb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some notes here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/guides/warehousing.html#use-cloudant-to-create-a-dashdb-warehouse

### Copy paste of the first part of the section "Keeping the data and structure fresh"

Data is loaded from Cloudant into dashDB using a replication process. This means that if your Cloudant data is updated or modified in some way, replication of the documents into dashDB must take place again to ensure your analytic tasks continue to work using the most up-to-date information.

As with normal Cloudant replication, data is transferred one-way only: for a warehouse the transfer is from Cloudant to dashDB. After the initial load of data, the warehouse subscribes to data content changes in the Cloudant database. Any changes are replicated from the Cloudant source to the dashDB target. This means that warehousing is a form of continuous replication from Cloudant to dashDB.

Over time, your Cloudant database might also have structural changes. This might include the addition or removal of fields from the JSON documents. When this happens, the schema used by the warehouse might become invalid, resulting in errors reported when fresh data is replicated from Cloudant to dashDB.

To solve this problem, Cloudant warehousing has a 'rescan' facility.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i should have read the documentation more clearly. My understanding is the default behavior is to copy all the schema and data initially and every sync will push new changes. If there are schema changes then re-scan needs to be done to accommodate new schema changes and that time it does a fresh load.